# Display error when the query dont return result in mysql

Tags: php, mysql

I am building an application  that gives user the opportunity to click on the day of the calendar and when there is an activity registered on that day, it shows a table with the activity registered...my problem is that when there is no activity on that day, I wont it to return the string : There is no activity.. I try to make it using `if($nrofrows>0)`like below but all the time it returns me the string :there is not activity, even I have activity on that day.
Please can you help me ? where is my error? Thanks in advance...

```
<body>

<?php 


mysql_connect("127.0.0.1","root","") or die("Smund te lidhet me serverin");
mysql_select_db("axhenda") or die("Kjo databaze nuk u gjet");

session_start();


$perdoruesi=$_SESSION['user_id'];



$result= mysql_query("SELECT * FROM Aktiviteti where Data= '$_POST[dataoutput]' and Perd_Id='$perdoruesi'");

$nrofrows= mysql_num_rows($result);

if($nrofrows>0)
{
    ?>

<div class="title"> Aktivitetet per daten <?php print ("$_POST[dataoutput]"); ?></div>

<form name="form1" method="post" action="delete.php">
<table >

  <th>

<th ><strong>Emri </strong></th>
<th ><strong>Pershkrimi </strong></th>
<th><strong>Ora</strong></th>
</th>

<?php

while ($row=mysql_fetch_array($result)) {
?>

<tr>
<td ><input name="checkbox[]" type="checkbox" value="<?php echo $row['Id_Akt']; ?>"></td>
<td style="font-size:0.9em"><?php echo $row['Emri']; ?></td>
<td ><?php echo $row['Pershkrimi']; ?></td>
<td><?php echo $row['Ora']; ?></td>
</tr>

<?php
}
?>


</table>
<input class="button" name="delete" type="submit" value="Delete" style="margin-left:40%; margin-top:100px; width:15%">




</form>

<?php
}

else {

echo "<span id='errorformat'>There is no activity on this day!<span>";}
?>


</body>

</html>
```

Comment: try looking at your query like so: `$query = "SELECT * FROM Aktiviteti where Data= '$_POST[dataoutput]' and Perd_Id='$perdoruesi'";` then on the next line below make `$result = mysql_query($query);` Then add the line `echo $query;` after `$query` is defined to see if the values of your variables are assigned properly.

Comment: Thanks, but I solve it....I have been trying to solve it all the day but now I saw that the problem is when I call the query to take the name of user...I take this part off and now it function.

Answer (score 0):

Might be a problem with the query you can add this to see:

```
$result= mysql_query("SELECT * FROM Aktiviteti where Data= '$_POST[dataoutput]' and Perd_Id='$perdoruesi'") or die ("query error" .mysql_error());
```

mysql_num_rows($result) returns false when there is an error so you might want to add this:

```
if($nrofrows && $nrofrows>0)
```

Answer (score 0):

try this

```
 if ( mysql_num_rows($result) > 0 ) {

 }
```